# Как можно сделать подобные комментарии?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Комментарии (изображение .gif): [http://i.imgur.com/tdNRdn4.gif](https://i.imgur.com/tdNRdn4.gif)

Как можно увидеть, когда пользователь нажимает +, то комментарии подгружаются, т.е. идет POST запрос (ответ приходит в JSON). Если же пользователь нажимает + и комментариев нет, тогда запрос не делается, а открывается форма. При добавлении комментария через форму идет POST запрос и добавляется div.

---

Вопрос: как можно сделать подобные комментарии? (Естественно, на стороне клиента).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам код нужен?
http://jsfiddle.net/joqnznq7/

Answer (score 1):

когда нет коментариев выставлять флаг - нетКомментариев и по условию либо отправлять запрос, либо показывать комментарии...